# Itextsharp pdfwriter getimported page grow file size

Tags: pdf, itext

I tried to overlap a model pdf, to see the differences between that and my new pdf.

here is my code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(WorkDir + "\\model.pdf");
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);

    pdfOut.NewPage(); 
    if (checkBox1.Checked) writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
```

I only want to put the page only if I check the checkbox1.
But if checkbox1 is not checked, the outout pdf file is very large and the overlapped file is not visible.

I removed the overlap part:

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(WorkDir + "\\model.pdf");
        //PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);

        pdfOut.NewPage(); 
        //if (checkBox1.Checked) writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
```

and the file size is now ok.

What am I doing wrong? 
I think that the DirectContent element adds the page, but is not visible.
That can explain why the output file is so big( with overlap part file size is 700KB, without only 4KB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data of the page are already added to the new document when importing the page

```
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
```

The later `writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);` only makes it visible.

Thus, you might want

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(WorkDir + "\\model.pdf");

pdfOut.NewPage(); 
if (checkBox1.Checked)
{
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
    writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I understand how getimportedpage works. I imagined that in Pdfimportedpage I get the page needed and addTemplate effectively puts the page in my pdf.